# how to remove share button from image overlay

Tags: plugins, images

does anyone know how I can remove share button from image overlay on my website ?, I already have a share button on my site, I dont want uploaded images to have share buttons too,  please help [image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find out which sources cause these sharing buttons.

- Is it your theme?

  - Then head over to the customizer of your them and look for an option describing these buttons.
  - If you can't find an option, check out the theme documentation.
- Is it a plugin?

  - Depending on the amount of the installed plugins, you can disable/enable these and see if the sharing disappear.
  - Once you know the plugin, which is causing this behaviour, check out the plugin options.

In case you can't find an option to control it via the admin interface, you can still visually remove the buttons using CSS `display: none`.

To hide them, open your web inspector and copy the element selector, add the `display: none;` declaration under your selector and paste the CSS rule to the custom CSS section in the WordPress customizer.